# Ordering of the commands used to install from a ppa

Tags: command-line, apt, ppa

To install from a ppa, you have to use the following 3 commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository example/program
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install example-program
```

Is there any reason not to do this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository example/program
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install example-program
```

or this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository example/program && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install example-program
```

or even this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository example/program && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install example-program
```

Is there any technical difference between them all?

Comment: If you are going to use `&&`, use it for all of them.

Comment: As long as they are in the order of 1. Add Repository  2. Update and 3. Install, it doesn't matter how you do those lines.  You also can add `-y` to a statement so it doesn't stop asking for input, i.e. `sudo apt-add-repository -y repository example` will auto add the repository without prompting you to press `Enter` to add the repository to the system.

Comment: @muru so this http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/04/gnome-pie-launcher-ubuntu-ppa is pointless...? (Scroll to the bottom).

Comment: @Tim well, yes. If the `add-apt-repository` fails, but `apt-get update` succeeds, the install command would still fail.

Comment: @muru I see what you are saying as the `&&` would not allow the `apt-get update` to run if the `apt-add-repsository` failed.  But if he ran the `apt-add-repository` on a separate line, he would already know that.

Comment: @Terrance Indeed. And many people do copy-paste both lines together (and if you'd used `sudo` short while before, then the password prompt wouldn't swallow the rest of the command).

Comment: @muru Good point.  `sudo` will only ask on the first time it is used as the password for `sudo` command by default is stored for 15 minutes per terminal session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `&&` operator executes the following command only upon success of the previous command / chain of commands.

So the implications for those cases are:

1. The script executes every command regardless
2. The scripts executes `sudo add-apt-repository example/program` and `sudo apt-get update` regardless and `sudo apt-get install example-program` only upon success of `sudo apt-get update`
3. The scripts executes `sudo add-apt-repository example/program` regardless, `sudo apt-get update` only upon success of `sudo add-apt-repository example/program` and `sudo apt-get install example-program` regardless
4. The scripts executes `sudo add-apt-repository example/program` regardless, `sudo apt-get update` only upon success of `sudo add-apt-repository example/program` and `sudo apt-get install example-program` only upon success of `sudo add-apt-repository example/program`

So, to answer your question, in this case just chain all of them, since you need everything to succeed:

```
sudo add-apt-repository example/program && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install example-program
```

Also, `add-apt-repository` and `apt-get` can be set to automatically answer yes to all queries using the `-y` argument, so to fully automate everything:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y example/program && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y example-program
```

Comment: @Tim Done, check the update

Answer (score 4):

If `;` was used they would be the same, but `&&` continues only if the command prior to it sends a exit code saying it exited successfully. It will automatically continue if all goes well, and will only stop to prompt the user to ask whether they want to add the PPA and whether they want to install the package. <sub>*It may also work better than the three-liner if all the exit codes produced by the programs are accurate, as the user may continue to enter the commands and not noticed the first or second failed.*</sub>

If you want to go all the way of automatically continuing:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository -y example/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y example-program
```

If you want to use it that's fine *(just be prepared that `apt-get` can have a ‘nice’ habit of destroying things if not used wisely, so don't use a odd ppa or much around too muck with dependencies)*, but if you want to document about installing a program I would recommend use one of the two or three liners *(without `-y`)*, as it allows the user more control over what happens, making them happier and preventing nasty accidents *(and as @Zacharee1 says, it is easier to understand, learn, & remember as separate lines - new users may not understand that they can separate the lines out, or may assume that as the command(s) in one string are so long that they obviously may do something evil)*

Some `&&` etc examples:

```
 $ true && echo "this will show output as that thing ← said it exited successfully"
this will show output as that thing ← said it exited successfully
 $ false && echo "this won't"
 $ false || echo "but this will"
but this will
 $ true || echo "weird init?"
 $ true ; echo " ← and this"
and this
 $ false ; echo "doesn't care"
doesn't care
 $ echo $?
0
 $ echo "previous exit code ↑" ; true
previous exit code ↑
 $ echo "previous exit code ↑"
previous exit code ↑
 $
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything there is the same thing. I think the reason it's usually listed the way it is is because it looks better and is easier to remember, since the commands are split up.

Comment: I noticed that right after I said it.

Comment: you could edit in he could have used just & ;)